# How to save GNOME Terminal contents with ANSI escape codes?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, screenshot, xterm

VT100 terminals have a relatively simple way to [save terminal contents with escape codes to a file](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/80c92286d6c637c848dbac73c531a0745e9ba8be) using <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>p</kbd>:

```
XTerm.VT100.printAttributes: 2
XTerm.VT100.printerCommand: cat - > file
XTerm.VT100.translations: #override Meta <KeyPress> P: print() \n
```

I've looked around quite a bit, and can't find a solution for this to work in the default GNOME Terminal + XTerm + Bash.

I do *not* want just an image with the contents of the window.

It looks like GNOME Terminal might eventually get [a fix for this](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=24457), but there's no information about which version it will be included in, and it's been almost three years since the last update...

Comment: Unfortunately, there is simply no way to do this. See: http://askubuntu.com/q/20739

Comment: @Josh I don't think that's the same question. I don't want to save all output from a command, but rather all visible output in the Terminal window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, l0b0 the answer out of the box is: This is not possible.

In my other answer, I listed how to use script to do this, though there are some differences as you noted. The other way is to compile the source or use an unstable version.

[Gnome Terminal Source Tarball](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-terminal/)

The version in Raring is 3.6.1, so you can look at this source. Inside of Terminal-window.c on line 115:

```
/*
 * We don't want to enable content saving until vte supports it async.
 * So we disable this code for stable versions.
 */

#include "terminal-version.h"

#if (TERMINAL_MINOR_VERSION & 1) != 0
#define ENABLE_SAVE
#else
#undef ENABLE_SAVE
#endif
#endif
```

Options:

1. Add #define ENABLE_SAVE under this.
2. Modify the version to an unstable.
3. Download an unstable version of the .DEB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does this save the ANSI escape keys, or just the text?

Comment: I've verified and vte_terminal_write_contents() doesn't appear to write ANSI codes out, at the moment, my original response is the most accurate "What you want is not possible (out of the box)." 

If you are developer-minded you can probably rewrite the function in termainal-window.c

    3340 save_contents_dialog_on_response(...)

At about line 3372 you see where the call to vte_terminal_write_contents is made. I am not going to go further  as it is beyond the scope of this site. Other terminals do offer this at far less of a cost than recompiling your utilities.

Comment: +100. If possible I would split it between this and your other answer, since they both do 90% of what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, l0b0 the answer out of the box is: This is not possible.

There are two ways you can attempt to rectify this, by running script at all times on your terminal and logging all output. Open up gnome-terminal, go to **Edit**->**Profile Preferences**, then the tab **Title and Command** and for your custom command use this:

```
bash -l -c 'script -q -c bash $HOME/sessionlogs/$BASHPID.sessionlog.$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M).txt'
```

Make sure 'sessionlogs' exists under $HOME.

**The other way has been removed and added as a second answer on this question.**

Comment: Indeed, corrected the answer to fix the typo which occurred during a repaste. I am separating out the 'recompile' option as well, as I agree the two are unrelated.

Comment: `less -r` actually shows the output as printed - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can run your shells via [script(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/script.1.html) to get all input and output of the terminal stored in a file, including terminal escapes.

Comment: That's a different use case. `script` can't be used to save content after the fact and it doesn't simply save the *visible output*.

Comment: Are you sure? True it can't save scripts after the fact, but when I tested this and output some file permissions with `ll` it saved all the output.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package that's called **screen** - a terminal multiplexor with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation.

According to the [manpage of **screen** on the Ubuntu Manuals website](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/screen.1.html) , **screen** claims to be

> a  full-screen  window  manager that multiplexes a physical terminal between  several  processes  (typically  interactive  shells).Each  virtual  terminal  provides the functions of [a DEC VT100 terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VT100) and, in addition, several control functions from the ISO 6429 (ECMA 48, ANSI X3.64) and ISO 2022 standards (e.g. insert/delete line and support for multiple character sets) a terminal multiplexor with VT100/ANSI terminal emulation'.

and when running **screen**:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>       (hardcopy)    Write a hardcopy of the current window to the file "hardcopy.n".

I tried in the GNOME Terminal, running `screen` and typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

[image: running screen and typing Ctrl Alt h]

This is the output of my hardcopy.1 file when opened in Gedit:

[image: hardcopy.1 opened in Gedit]

You can find **screen** is in the raring/main software repository of Ubuntu 13.04.

It's not installed by default.

Answer (score -1):

Hm, this will not copy the escape codes, but just to grab the text, you can go to menu Edit -> Select All, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and either (i) paste the clipboard to an editor or (ii) type `cat > filename` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: This is a different use case - As explicitly stated, I want to include the ANSI escape codes.

Answer (score -1):

`man history`
look for history expansion for escaped characters.
I believe `history`  can do what youre asking.

Comment: I could find nothing relevant in the `man` page. Please be more specific.